# Guard runs in Terminal but not iTerm2

Tags: ruby, sass, guard

When I try to run guard in iTerm2, I get the following output. (It runs fine in Terminal.)

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find guard (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/guard:18:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Some other details: I'm using oh-my-zsh with iTerm2. I'm also using oh-my-zsh with Terminal, where I have no issues.

This is not a Rails app. It's just a directory with a Guardfile used for Guard Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. It was because I was not running iTerm2 as a login shell.

I went to iTerm2 Preferences -> Profiles Tab. Under *Command* I selected the option for Login shell, instead of the option for Command.

Restarted iTerm2. Guard runs without errors.

Comment: Great job jthomas. Don't forget to mark your question as answered in 2 days when it lets you!

Comment: Did you actually switch from Command: "login -fp Username" to "Login Shell"? Is it something that changed lately in Term2?
I was not able to sudo anymore. After an upgrade I was getting "Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported" when trying to sudo. It sounded strange.

Comment: My command had "/bin/zsh -i" in it, but yes, I literally selected the radio button for "Login Shell" rather than the radio button for "Command." I haven't experienced the issue you're referring to with sudo.